# ARM Cortex-M3 — Why might I (appear to) receive a UsageFault on a PUSH instruction?

Tags: assembly, cortex-m

I'm having some trouble diagnosing the cause of an INVSTATE UsageFault that *appears* to be occurring on a `push` instruction in a particular circumstance.

Here's what I know:

1. If this segment of code runs from a 'fresh' boot, it runs as expected.
2. If this segment of code runs after a software RESET, I drop in to forced hard fault which (unless I'm reading it wrong) suggests itself to be an `INVSTATE` `UsageFault`.

Here are the registers just before the instruction runs on fresh boot:

```
(gdb) info registers
r0             0x8001000    134221824
r1             0x8020000    134348800
r2             0x8020000    134348800
r3             0x40022014   1073881108
r4             0x0  0
r5             0x0  0
r6             0x0  0
r7             0x20009fc0   536911808
r8             0x0  0
r9             0x0  0
r10            0x0  0
r11            0x0  0
r12            0x0  0
sp             0x20009fc0   0x20009fc0
lr             0x8000259    134218329
pc             0x8000178    0x8000178 <wait_for_busy>
xPSR           0x81000000   -2130706432
```

... and here they are just before the instruction after software reset:

```
(gdb) info registers
r0             0x8001000    134221824
r1             0x8020000    134348800
r2             0x8020000    134348800
r3             0x40022014   1073881108
r4             0x4028   16424
r5             0x0  0
r6             0x20009a90   536910480
r7             0x20009fc0   536911808
r8             0x4028   16424
r9             0x0  0
r10            0x0  0
r11            0x0  0
r12            0x0  0
sp             0x20009fc0   0x20009fc0
lr             0x8000259    134218329
pc             0x8000178    0x8000178 <wait_for_busy>
xPSR           0x81000000   -2130706432
```

Some more facts:

- Stack high address is `0x2000A000`.
- `lr` contains the expected value (instruction after branch to this func).

The instructions at and just after `pc` are:

```
(gdb) disassemble 0x08000178
Dump of assembler code for function wait_for_busy:
   0x08000178 <+0>: push    {r7}
   0x0800017a <+2>: sub sp, #12
   0x0800017c <+4>: add r7, sp, #0
   0x0800017e <+6>: ldr r3, [pc, #28]   ; (0x800019c <wait_for_busy+36>)
   0x08000180 <+8>: str r3, [r7, #4]
   0x08000182 <+10>:    nop
```

If I break at `0x08000178`, then `nexti`, I drop in to an exception handler. Registers are now:

```
(gdb) info register
r0             0x8001000    134221824
r1             0x8020000    134348800
r2             0x8020000    134348800
r3             0xe000ed04   -536810236
r4             0x4028   16424
r5             0x0  0
r6             0x20009a90   536910480
r7             0x20009fc0   536911808
r8             0x4028   16424
r9             0x0  0
r10            0x0  0
r11            0x0  0
r12            0x0  0
sp             0x20009f78   0x20009f78
lr             0xfffffff1   -15
pc             0x8000368    0x8000368 <Stub_Handler+2>
xPSR           0x81000003   -2130706429
```

A frame up is:

```
0x20009f98: 0x08001000  0x08020000  0x08020000  0x40022014
0x20009fa8: 0x00000000  0x08000259  0x08000178  0x81000200
```

The value of the HFSR is (below), suggesting a forced hard fault:

```
(gdb) x/1wx 0xE000ED2C
0xe000ed2c: 0x40000000
```

The value of the CSFR is (below), suggesting an `INVSTATE` UsageFault:

```
(gdb) x/1wx 0xE000ED28
0xe000ed28: 0x00020000
```

The description for `INVSTATE` is:

> When this bit is set to 1, the PC value stacked for the exception return points to the instruction that attempted the illegal use of the EPSR.

And this is where I'm stuck. What might be different after a software reset that could cause this? Is this even the *real* problem?

Any direction on where to go from here would be great!

Comment: The value in LR after nexti indicates that a nested exception has occurred. The value in SP is also 72 bytes lower than it was before nexti. That's room for two 32 byte long exception stack frames. You should look at the most recent exception stack frame at 0x20009f78 to find out which handler was interrupted and then inspect its code. Given the values in HFSR and CSFR, I'd guess either one of your exception handler vectors does't have the least significant bit set or the first exception handler invoked didn't return properly.

Comment: This sounds promising, I'll investigate shortly! What about the LR indicates nesting? All I've seen in the docs is a table at the bottom of http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/Babefdjc.html

Comment: The "Returns to Handler mode" part indicates that its returning to a (nested) handler.

Comment: Thank you! Sure enough, it was trying to call the handler for IRQ49 at 0x0! For some reason when reading out the 'previous' frame I had it in my mind I'd need to jump up 8 words first — foolish. If you were to submit this as an answer, I'd accept it.